# Prevent caching in a specific page react

Tags: reactjs

I having problem when switching pages for my react app

supposedly i have this page that displays item information for example

items/1231231231231 = display the items for that specific id and then when i move to another item using Link

```
<Link to{'/items/22334567'}
```

to move to another item and display the item infos, on its initial render the item infos from the first item (items/1231231231231) is displayed first or loaded first then after the data has been fetched for the new item, it will only display the correct information for the next item ('/items/22334567') . I understand that it is important to cache files so that when user access the same data again the browser will not fetch the data again, but the thing is this interaction is kinda confusing in my part, so I want to disable caching or displaying of the first information before loading the next information by comparing their (id) this is what im thinking. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to clear the state when you start loading new data on change of item id. I have to assume how your Item component code looks like but let us say you have a state `items` and a setter `setItems`. If you load your data in a `useEffect`, you can do something like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setItems([]);
  // display loader
  // code to fetch items
}, [props.itemId]
```

If you load new items, another way e.g. in Redux or something, please think about the exact step where you need to reset the items to an empty array. It could be the reducer or some other place.

Comment: hello, I think my states are all on memory, and im getting all of my data directly from it, im using react redux, and those states are immutable if im correct. This is could be a possible solution if I refactor again my code . Thanks!

Comment: Could you please update your question with more code explaining how your component and data fetching works? If you load data using a Redux action, you can reset the items in Redux reducer initially, when the fetch action is first fired i.e. before it is fulfilled.